# Returning a Column in Vue Data grid a a clickable button

Tags: javascript, web, vue.js

I am trying to use vue.js grid to show a bunch of columns with calculated texts and one clickable column in the end which does some action dynamically based on the parameter.(calling an api in laravel for example)

When I return the last column as a clickable link, the vue.js prints me the  tag instead of showing it in the grid. What Am I doing wrong?
VueCode:

```
  // register the grid component
    Vue.component('demo-grid', {
      template: '#grid-template',
      props: {
        data: Array,
        columns: Array,
        filterKey: String
      },
      data: function () {
        var sortOrders = {}
        this.columns.forEach(function (key) {
          sortOrders[key] = 1
        })
        return {
          sortKey: '',
          sortOrders: sortOrders
        }
      },
      computed: {
        filteredData: function () {
          var sortKey = this.sortKey
          var filterKey = this.filterKey && this.filterKey.toLowerCase()
          var order = this.sortOrders[sortKey] || 1
          var data = this.data
          if (filterKey) {
            data = data.filter(function (row) {
              return Object.keys(row).some(function (key) {
                return String(row[key]).toLowerCase().indexOf(filterKey) > -1
              })
            })
          }
          if (sortKey) {
            data = data.slice().sort(function (a, b) {
              a = a[sortKey]
              b = b[sortKey]
              return (a === b ? 0 : a > b ? 1 : -1) * order
            })
          }
          return data
        }
      },
      filters: {
        capitalize: function (str) {
          return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1)
        }
      },
      methods: {
        sortBy: function (key) {
          this.sortKey = key
          this.sortOrders[key] = this.sortOrders[key] * -1
        }
      }
    })

    // bootstrap the demo
    var demo = new Vue({
      el: '#demo',
      data: {
        searchQuery: '',
        gridColumns: ['name', 'power','report'],
        gridData: [
          { name: 'Chuck s', power: Infinity },
          { name: 'Bruce Lee', power: 9000 },
          { name: 'Jackie Chan', power: 7000 },
          { name: 'Jet Li', power: 8000 ,report: '<a href="http://www.google.com>Google</a>"'}
        ]
      }
    })
```

HTML file:

```
<script type="text/x-template" id="grid-template">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th v-for="key in columns"
          @click="sortBy(key)"
          :class="{ active: sortKey == key }">
          {{ key | capitalize }}
          <span class="arrow" :class="sortOrders[key] > 0 ? 'asc' : 'dsc'">
          </span>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="entry in filteredData">
        <td v-for="key in columns">
          {{entry[key]}}
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</script>

<!-- demo root element -->
<div id="demo">
  <form id="search">
    Search <input name="query" v-model="searchQuery">
  </form>
  <demo-grid
    :data="gridData"
    :columns="gridColumns"
    :filter-key="searchQuery">
  </demo-grid>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `v-html` directive to interpret it properly like `<td v-for="key in columns" v-html="entry[key]">`

**Note**
set `"` properly here :

`{ name: 'Jet Li', power: 8000 ,report: '<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>'}`

```js
Vue.component('demo-grid', {
  template: `<table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th v-for="key in columns"
          @click="sortBy(key)"
          :class="{ active: sortKey == key }">
          {{ key | capitalize }}
          <span class="arrow" :class="sortOrders[key] > 0 ? 'asc' : 'dsc'">
          </span>
        </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr v-for="entry in filteredData">
        <td v-for="key in columns" v-html="entry[key]">
        
        </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>`,
  props: {
    data: Array,
    columns: Array,
    filterKey: String
  },
  data: function() {
    var sortOrders = {}
    this.columns.forEach(function(key) {
      sortOrders[key] = 1
    })
    return {
      sortKey: '',
      sortOrders: sortOrders
    }
  },
  computed: {
    filteredData: function() {
      var sortKey = this.sortKey
      var filterKey = this.filterKey && this.filterKey.toLowerCase()
      var order = this.sortOrders[sortKey] || 1
      var data = this.data
      if (filterKey) {
        data = data.filter(function(row) {
          return Object.keys(row).some(function(key) {
            return String(row[key]).toLowerCase().indexOf(filterKey) > -1
          })
        })
      }
      if (sortKey) {
        data = data.slice().sort(function(a, b) {
          a = a[sortKey]
          b = b[sortKey]
          return (a === b ? 0 : a > b ? 1 : -1) * order
        })
      }
      return data
    }
  },
  filters: {
    capitalize: function(str) {
      return str.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + str.slice(1)
    }
  },
  methods: {
    sortBy: function(key) {
      this.sortKey = key
      this.sortOrders[key] = this.sortOrders[key] * -1
    }
  }
})

// bootstrap the demo
var demo = new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    searchQuery: '',
    gridColumns: ['name', 'power', 'report'],
    gridData: [{
        name: 'Chuck s',
        power: Infinity
      },
      {
        name: 'Bruce Lee',
        power: 9000
      },
      {
        name: 'Jackie Chan',
        power: 7000
      },
      {
        name: 'Jet Li',
        power: 8000,
        report: '<a href="http://www.google.com">Google</a>'
      }
    ]
  }
})
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="description" content="Vue.delete">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.2.1/vue.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="demo">
    <div id="grid-template">

    </div>

    <!-- demo root element -->
    <div id="demo">
      <form id="search">
        Search <input name="query" v-model="searchQuery">
      </form>
      <demo-grid :data="gridData" :columns="gridColumns" :filter-key="searchQuery">
      </demo-grid>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply. It fixed my problem.